# Animate tabs delays after selecting a tab

Tags: react-native, expo

So working with `react-native` I wanted to create my own `tabMenu` both for learning and also have more controll.

Now it was not that hard to create one but I am having a little issue with animation delay when clicking on tabs, the delay is not that long but I am wondering why it happen so specifically when I animate on press.

here is my code

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Animated,
  Easing,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView,
  SafeAreaView
} from "react-native";

import View from "./ThemeView";
import * as Icons from "@expo/vector-icons";
import {
  useState,
  useEffect,
  ReactNode,
  useRef
} from "react";
import {
  sleep,
  newId,
  removeProps,
  proc
} from "../Methods";
import GlobalData from "../GlobalContext";
import { useUpdate } from "../hooks";
import Text from "./ThemeText";
import { TabIcon, TabChild } from "../Types";
const TabBar = ({
  children,
  selectedIndex,
  style,
  position,
  disableScrolling,
  change,
  rootView,
  scrollHeight,
  fontSize
}: {
  children: TabChild[];
  style?: any;
  selectedIndex?: number;
  position?: "Bottom" | "Top";
  disableScrolling: boolean;
  change?: (index) => void;
  rootView?: boolean;
}) => {
  //GlobalData.hook("theme.settings");
  const [size, setSize] = useState(undefined);
  const [rItems, setrItems] = useState(
    children.map(x => {})
  );
  const animLeft = useRef(
    new Animated.Value(0)
  ).current;
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(
    (0).sureValue(selectedIndex)
  );
  const isAnimating = useRef(false);
  let loadChildren = (i: number) => {
    if (!rItems[i] && children[i]) {
      rItems[i] = {
        child: childPrep(children[i])
      };
    }

    setIndex(i);
    animateLeft(i);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadChildren(index);
  }, [size]);

  useEffect(
    () => {
      children.forEach((x, i) => {
        if (rItems[i]) {
          rItems[i].child = childPrep(x);
        }
      });

      loadChildren(index);
    },
    children.map(x => x)
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    loadChildren(selectedIndex);
  }, [selectedIndex]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (index !== undefined) change?.(index);
  }, [index]);

  const animateLeft = async (index: number) => {
    while (isAnimating.current) await sleep(100);
    if (!size || isAnimating.current) return;
    isAnimating.current = true;
    Animated.timing(animLeft, {
      toValue: index,
      duration: 300,
      useNativeDriver: true
    }).start(() => {
      isAnimating.current = false;
    });
  };

  const getWidth = (index: number) => {
    let v = index * size?.width;
    if (isNaN(v)) return 0;
    return v;
  };

  const childPrep = child => {
    if (child) {
      if (!child.props.style) return child;
      if (Array.isArray(child.props.style))
        child.props.style.push({ flex: 1 });
      else child.props.style.flex = 1;
    }
    return child;
  };

  const getIcon = (
    icon?: TabIcon,
    iconSize,
    style
  ) => {
    if (!icon) return null;
    let Type = Icons[icon.type];
    if (Type)
      return (
        <Type
          name={icon.name}
          size={(15).sureValue(iconSize)}
          style={removeProps(
            style,
            "backgroundColor"
          )}
        />
      );
  };

  let menu = (
    <View
      style={[
        styles.menu,
        GlobalData.theme.invertSettings()
      ]}>
      {children.map((x, i) => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={[
            styles.menuBtn,
            i == (0).sureValue(index)
              ? GlobalData.theme.settings
              : undefined
          ]}
          key={i + "txt"}
          onPress={() => loadChildren(i)}>
          {getIcon(
            x.props.icon,
            i == (0).sureValue(index) ? 15 : 18,
            [
              styles.menuText,
              GlobalData.theme.invertSettings(),
              i == (0).sureValue(index)
                ? GlobalData.theme.settings
                : undefined
            ]
          )}
          {!(x.props.title || "").empty() ? (
            <Text
              invertColor={true}
              style={[
                styles.menuText,
                { fontSize },
                i == (0).sureValue(index)
                  ? GlobalData.theme.settings
                  : undefined
              ]}>
              {x.props.title}
            </Text>
          ) : null}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
  return (
    <View
      rootView={rootView}
      style={[
        style,
        {
          flex: 1,
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
          overflow: "hidden",
          backgroundColor: "inherit"
        }
      ]}
      onLayout={event => {
        setSize(event.nativeEvent.layout);
      }}>
      {position === "Top" ? menu : null}
      <Animated.View
        style={[
          styles.container,
          {
            transform: [
              {
                translateX: animLeft.interpolate({
                  inputRange: children.map(
                    (x, i) => i
                  ),
                  outputRange: children.map(
                    (x, i) =>
                      i == 0 ? 0 : -getWidth(i)
                  )
                })
              }
            ],
            height: (0).sureValue(
              size?.height - styles.menu.height
            ),
            width:
              (size?.width ?? 0) * children.length
          }
        ]}>
        {children.map((x, i) => (
          <View
            css="flex"
            key={i}>
            {x.props.head}
            {!disableScrolling &&
            !x.props.disableScrolling ? (
              <ScrollView
                style={{
                  width: size?.width,
                  maxHeight: scrollHeight
                }}
                contentContainerStyle={{
                  flexGrow: 1,
                  padding: 5,
                  width: size?.width
                }}>
                {rItems[i]?.child ?? null}
              </ScrollView>
            ) : (
              rItems[i]?.child
            )}
          </View>
        ))}
      </Animated.View>
      {position !== "Top" ? menu : null}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "95%",
    flexDirection: "row",
    display: "flex",
    position: "relative",
    backgroundColor: "transparent"
  },
  menuBtn: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    height: "100%",
    flex: 1,
    borderRadius: 0
  },
  menuText: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    alignSelf: "center",
    textTransform: "uppercase"
  },
  menu: {
    position: "relative",
    width: "100%",
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    alignItems: "center",
    height: 40,
    backgroundColor: "transparent"
  }
});

export default TabBar;
```

and for creating it

```
import Home from "./Home";
import Favorit from "./Favorit";
import Settings from "./Settings";
import Downloaded from "./Downloaded";
import Header from "./Header";
import { TabBar, View } from "../components";
import { useState } from "react";
export default ({ ...props }) => {
  return (
    <TabBar
      rootView={true}
      fontSize={9}>
      <Home
        disableScrolling={true}
        {...props}
        icon={{
          name: "home",
          type: "Entypo"
        }}
        title="home"
      />

      <Favorit
        {...props}
        disableScrolling={true}
        icon={{
          name: "favorite",
          type: "MaterialIcons"
        }}
        title="Favorit"
      />
      <Downloaded
        {...props}
        disableScrolling={true}
        icon={{
          name: "download-for-offline",
          type: "MaterialIcons"
        }}
        title="Downloads"
      />
      <Settings
        {...props}
        icon={{
          name: "settings",
          type: "Ionicons"
        }}
        title="Settings"
      />
    </TabBar>
  );
};
```